# Save selected day in MySQL with jXDatePicker

Tags: java, mysql, swing

The code need to save the day selected by the user in the data base, but i can't return the value in sql.date, my code is:

```
  private java.sql.Date convertUtilToSql (Date fecha)
   {
       java.sql.Date sDate = convertUtilToSql(fecha);
       return sDate; 

   }
```

and the message is: "The method convertUtilToSql will recurse infinitely"

Comment: 1) Don't post screenshots of code, but the text of the code! 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

`java.sql.Date sDate = convertUtilToSql(fecha);` you are calling the method over and over again with this line. it never gets to the return statement. replace the line i posted with `java.sql.Date sqlVon = new java.sql.Date(fecha.getTime());`. then it should work